# How can join dynamic collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I need to join with a collection that is selected from the field

collection: master

| _id | collection | refId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| M101 | related_a | A101 |
| M102 | related_b | B101 |

collection: related_a

| _id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| A101 | A-111 |
| A102 | A-222 |

collection: related_b

| _id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| B101 | B-111 |
| B102 | B-222 |

**Expected Output**

| _id | collection | relatedItem |
| --- | --- | --- |
| M101 | related_a | {refId:A101, name:A-111} |
| M102 | related_b | {refId:B101, name:B-111} |

```
db.master.aggregate([
{
   $lookup: {
       from: ,// Base on collection field value
       localField: 'refId',
       foreignField: '_id',
       as: 'relatedItem'
   }
}
]);
```

Comment: you cant do this, from must be a string, it cant be an expression. But if you know the collection name before sending the query you can do it with the app code, dynamically.

Comment: This looks like a poor data design, you may review it. Note, NoSQL database like MongoDB are not like relational databases. Designing the data as you might used to it in SQL is typically not the best approach.

Comment: I can't embed related documents because we have multiple scenario where related document update frequently